# Sort a list of Python dictionaries depending on a ordered criteria

Tags: python, list, sorting

Hi, I want to order a list of dictionaries based on an ordered criteria in the most Pythonic way. For example:

```
[{'foo': FOO1}, {'foo': FOO2}, {'foo': FOO10}]
```

The criteria is variable, for example, I want to order first by [FOO2, FOO1, FOO8, FOO10], the result would be:

```
[{'foo': FOO2}, {'foo': FOO1}, {'foo': FOO10}]
```

Then, the situation changes and now we have another criteria [FOO2, FOO10, FOO1], the result would be:

```
[{'foo': FOO2}, {'foo': FOO10}, {'foo': FOO1}]
```

Note: The criteria will always have the symbols related to key 'foo'.

Any ideas?

```
to_sort = [{'foo': FOO1}, {'foo': FOO2}, {'foo': FOO10}]
to_sort.sort(key=lambda x: x....)
```

---

EDIT: I figured it out:

```
>>> to_sort = [{'foo': FOO1}, {'foo': FOO2}, {'foo': FOO10}]
>>> criteria = [FOO10, FOO2, FOO1]
>>> to_sort.sort(key=lambda x: criteria.index(x['foo']))
>>> to_sort
[{'foo': FOO10}, {'foo': FOO2}, {'foo': FOO1}]
```

Kind regards

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You want [`list.index()`](http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#mutable-sequence-types).